# What is "Lollipop"?

Tags: format-files, lollipop

I just read something about "[Lollipop](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/lollipop)" in an Stackexchange advertisement on this web page.

What is so different about it compared to other macros? What does it do so easily and what can it do? The readme didn't really give me much information about what it is.

Comment: It is a completely different format. `lollipop` vs `LaTeX` vs. `ConTeXt`

Comment: Try `texdoc lollipop` if you're on a reasonably up-to-date TeX Live system.

Comment: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/lollipop/doc/manual/lollipop-manual.pdf

Comment: It is also a symbol used in Linear Logic to denote the linear implication, written ⊸. See the package [CMLL](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cmll/) for more information.

Comment: @Clément TMYK, I suppose. :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

victor eijkhout introduced `lollipop` at the 1992 tug meeting.  the
[proceedings article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb13-3/eijkhout.pdf) resulting from his
talk describes it thus:

> The Lollipop format is a meta-format: it does not define user macros, but it
>   contains the tools with which a style designer can easily implement such user
>   macros.

victor used `lollipop`, along with guidance from a professional graphic designer,
to produce his dissertation, an elegant presentation.  `lollipop` also formed the
basis for defining the style of the first edition of *TeX by Topic* (that has since
been reformatted using a latex document class, but i really liked the original better).

i'm glad to see that `lollipop` has been resuscitated, although without victor
as maintainer.

**edit:**
since there seems to be confusion about how `lollipop` fits into the tex zoo, here's
how i understand it.

`lollipop` is a tool that allows one to create a style roughly equivalent to a
latex document class, and then launch a "format" (a starter set of macros
superimposed on the tex engine, as latex is) to compile a document using the
defined style. the essential difference is that defining the style is up to the user;
decisions aren't made beforehand, as they are with latex.

perhaps with time a body of predefined styles will accumulate, but for that,
a critical mass of users is needed first.

Comment: I've started working on the tag-wiki; it needs more love.

Comment: I have to admit that after reading your answer and even glancing at the manual, I still don't understand what Lollipop is concretely.

Comment: Thanks! I suggest you include that in your answer, since it is very relevant information for those of us who never heard about Lollipop.

Comment: @MartinArgerami -- done.