# What is a TeX format (e.g. LaTeX)?

Tags: tex-core

What is the meaning of the term "format", as used in [the following comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388269/expl3-latex3-latex2e-and-tex#comment962786_388269) I received to [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388269/21685) I posted on this forum:

> LaTeX3' isn't released as a format: perhaps you mean expl3?

[The answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388288/21685) I received to the above mentioned question also mentions this term:

> You can dump a format from the current expl3 but it will just do nothing because it doesn't provide basic things like an output routine. If you are already running some format (Plain TeX, LaTeX2e, ConTeXt, lollipop, etc) you can input the expl3 macro package and use everything it provides.
>
> ---
>
> I think you are asking whether there exists a format which has expl3 preloaded, to which the answer is no.

Comment: Basically a set of macros compiled into a single union.

Comment: @Johannes_B: What do you mean by "compiled into a single union"?

Comment: The format is compiled so that loading it is much faster than putting the exact same code into the document and compiling it at every run (kind of pre-compilation).

Comment: See [this answer by Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220496/124577).

Comment: We've had several questions in this area in the past: I suspect it's a dupe of the one already linked to or something similar.

Comment: @JosephWright: I searched for questions with "format" in the title before posting this one, and couldn't find any. But I think the question that TeXnician linked to might indeed be effectively what I'm asking. I'm not deleting my question, in case someone else searches for "format" as I did.

Comment: In terms of the program: a format is simply a “brain dump” of TeX's state (everything in its memory) after some stuff has been read. This is used to save time when TeX starts: e.g. instead of each time reading `plain.tex` as characters, doing tokenization+other computation, putting control sequences in the table of equivalents and assigning definitions to them etc., TeX can do this work once, dump the resulting state, and undump it from next time. So `tex gentle.tex` and `tex -jobname gentle -ini '\input plain \input gentle.tex'` are equivalent (except that the latter is a *tiny* bit slower).